# find a product inside a specific category using mongodb and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to mongodb. I'm trying to query for a particular product in a specific category (for example if I'm in the books category then I would like to query for a particular book by its name i.e., productName) but I'm unable to do so successfully. Could anybody help me with this. I'm attaching the schema below for reference.

```
 const categorySchema = {
   name: String,
   description: String,
   products: [
     {
       productName: String,
       price: String,
       thumbnail: String,
       description: String
     }
   ]
 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search by an object into an array you need to use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) and is very simple.

You need a query similar to this:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "_id": 0,
  "products.productName": "productName"
})
```

Note that the find has two conditions.

The first one is to look for in the document you want using its `_id` (if you want all documents which has 'productName' into the array this condition is not neccesary, but for query a single document it does). This is for query into a specific category document.

The second condition is to get those documents which has the value `productName` for the key `productName` into the array `products`.

Check an example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/a_ErnJd2hFx)

Also, if you want to return only the subdocument instead of the entire document, you need this query:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "_id": 0
},
{
  "products": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "productName": "productName"
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/trIoz_PpgLM)

Using `$elementMatch` only the subdocument is returned.

Also, using `mongoose` the query is the same. Something like this.

```js
var find = await model.find({
  "_id": 0,
  "products.productName": "productName"
})
```